# How to generate keystore for Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, keystore, pfx

I want to generate keystore file for authenticating the connection with Elasticsearch. Could you please guide me? Also I have one .pfx ssl certificate(password protected) with me. Can I convert the .Pfx to keystore for connecting elasticsearch.
Please note that I am using remote elasticsearch.